# Concrete5 Permissions on a block crawl-able by search engines?

Tags: seo, concrete5

I think I already know the answer to this, but a client is asking me if they create a block on a page that has permissions set to not allow guests to see, does that mean that search engine bots are unable to index it? I don't see anything in their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you are right. Search engines won't be able to see.

However you can test easily to be 100% - use the Fetch as Googlebot tool in Google Webmaster Tools.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en